# PowerBI: Change display unit based on values in table

Tags: powerbi-desktop

I want to show display units based on values in graphs. Like If value > 1000 then in Thousands ex:'5K', if value > 1000000 then in Millions ex: '5M', if value is < 1000 then value itself ex: 500.

Comment: Where do you want to display it, or in what visual? Most of the times Power BI provides the formatting option **auto** for **Display Units** which should do the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First the problem depends on where you want to display the value. Most visualizations offer a **Display format** option which can be set to auto to do the trick. It chooses one scale and puts all values on this scale. This makes sense as a bar chart compaing values in millions to values in hundreds hardly adds any visualiztion value as the diffirence is too big (unless using a logarithmic scale of course). For most occasions that will do the job just fine.

So let's assume a case in which you need to compare really large and small values. You can create a measure to change the formatting based on the size of the value. **One major downside is that the value is converted to text and can no longer be aggregated as a value in a visual requiring that.** You can still use it in a table or as tooltip in bar chart for instance as those fields de accept text values. In this case make sure the aggregating expression is evaluated before the conversion to text to match the context in your visual. I've done this by placing the calculation in a seperate variable which can also reference another measure.

```
Measure = 
    var calc = SUM ( 'Values'[Value] ) // could be any calculation or reference to other measure
    var decimals = "0.0"
RETURN
    SWITCH ( TRUE() ;
        calc > 1000000 ; FORMAT ( calc / 1000000 ; decimals & "M" ) ;
        calc > 1000 ; FORMAT ( calc / 1000 ; decimals & "K" ) ;
        FORMAT ( calc ; decimals )
    )
```

Comment: Thanks Jelle. This is exactly what I was looking for. But this works only for matrix or table. I want to display it for funnel graph as well. For values section it is not taking 'Measure' field. Could you help me with it.

Comment: Unfortunately, the exact thing you want is not possible. As I stated, this measure converts the values to text which is no big deal for a table or matrix as you pointed out. It is however problematic for a visual that requires a number to calculate the size of the visual element as in for instance a funnel chart. I think the best alternative for you would be to use the auto display format for the basic data labels and have this measure as a tooltip. It is simply not possible to conditionally format the units in a visual for now.

Comment: You could see if someone requested this feature and consider requesting it yourself but it will take a while considering the waiting list https://ideas.powerbi.com/forums/265200-power-bi-ideas?query=conditional%20units

Comment: Thanks Jelle for the answer. :)

Comment: I can't use it in a scroller